# Why does adding tab index to <a> tag cause it to affect the :focus behavior in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hyperlink, tabindex

Considering the following:

```
<a tabindex="0" href="">With TabIndex</a>
<a href="">Without TabIndex</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uLg7jyo9/1/

Mouse down on first link move away and mouse up, you will notice the blue border is still there.

do the same on the second link and you will notice it is not.

I want tab index to affect tab events not click events. How can I fix this?

Note: Firefox seems to treat them both the same.

Comment: Can you give some more details, it seems confusing

Comment: If you can supply with screen shots combined with steps as you described above would be good. Also I would recommend to report this issue to Google Chrome here https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en in summary if you can show the behavior without the tabindex and later with the tabindex to chrome team will be good things to do

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens, but adding `outline: none;` to your *a:focus* css will solve that issue.

Comment: Can I ask why you're adding a `tabindex` to your `<a>` elements? They're already focusable as it is.

In terms of why the functionality is displaying in this way, I believe it's a design decision from the Chrome developers to highlight where the current focus is. Essentially forcing `tabindex` makes a non-native focusable element focusable, and therefore when it receives focus it acts as though it has been tabbed to.

You _can_ use `outline: none;` to remove it, but if you do please create a new focus style - the impact on accessibility is horrific, check out: http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 a{
   outline:none
 }
```

add this style

Comment: Don't do this without serious thought, it has huge impacts on accessibility for users:
http://www.outlinenone.com

Comment: This is not an option for us. We are required to support tabbing.